# HTTP Error 400: Bad request to Firebase using Python

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-security

I am using the [python-firebase library by Ozgur Vatansever](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-firebase/1.2)  for my program.

I have previously been able to write/read data to my firebase, however with the introduction of authentication I cannot. Using:

```
from firebase import firebase

auth = firebase.FirebaseAuthentication('MY_FIREBASE_SECRET','myEmail@email.com') 
myFirebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://MYFIREBASE.firebaseio.com', auth)

result = myFirebase.get('/users', None) 
print result
```

Resulting in:

```
HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request
```

Conversely, using no authentication:

```
 myFirebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://MYFIREBASE.firebaseio.com', None)        
 result = myFirebase.get('/users', None)
```

works as expected. Any help in why I am getting this `HTTP error: 400`, when using authentication is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know nothing about Python, but looking at the [readme for python-firebase](https://github.com/mikexstudios/python-firebase), it shows the syntax as `f = Firebase('http://SampleChat.firebaseIO.com/', auth_token="<my_firebase_auth_token>")`

Comment: @Kato Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, that is for a different, lesser used python-firebase library. They actually have the same name! Edited question to reflect the specific library I am using.

Comment: Hi Eric. That clears things up a bit. So I only see a 400/Bad Request when the JWT token is invalid. If you can figure out how to log the JWT token, you could [try parsing it manually](http://jsfiddle.net/firebase/XDXu5/embedded/result/) to see if it is in fact broken. My guess here is that this will turn out to be a) an SSL compatibility issue (since SSL V3 has been dropped recently) or b) a change in the Firebase token parsing that makes this lib incompatible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using version 1.2 of the library and python 2.7
In  [here](https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase/blob/master/examples/firebase_example.py) there's an example on how to connect easily using auth.

```
import datetime

from firebase.firebase import FirebaseApplication, FirebaseAuthentication


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SECRET = '12345678901234567890'
    DSN = 'https://firebase.localhost'
    EMAIL = 'your@email.com'
    authentication = FirebaseAuthentication(SECRET,EMAIL, True, True)
    firebase = FirebaseApplication(DSN, authentication)

    firebase.get('/users', None,
        params={'print': 'pretty'},
        headers={'X_FANCY_HEADER': 'very fancy'})

data = {'name': 'Ozgur Vatansever', 'age': 26,
    'created_at': datetime.datetime.now()}

snapshot = firebase.post('/users', data)
print(snapshot['name'])

def callback_get(response):
    with open('/dev/null', 'w') as f:
        f.write(response)
firebase.get_async('/users', snapshot['name'], callback=callback_get)
```

[image: This is a test app so there's no issue with the secret]
[image: And here is the proof of the data being uploaded]
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem, and the problem seems to be that Firebase is rejecting the token that python-firebase builds (in FirebaseTokenGenerator).

I don't know what is wrong with the token being generated, and given that I am happy to use the JWT token provided in the Secrets section of the Firebase Dashboard, this hack works for me:

In firebase.py, class FirebaseAuthentication, right at the start of the get_user method, add an if clause:

```
def get_user(self):
    if self.extra.get('explicitAuth') is None:
            token = self.authenticator.create_token(self.extra)
    else:
            token = self.extra.get('explicitAuth')
```

Then when invoking the application provide the explicit token overriding the generated one:

```
auth = firebase.FirebaseAuthentication('Ignore', 'Ignore', extra={'explicitAuth': myToken})
app = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://mystuff.firebaseio.com/', auth)
```

Comment: Hello, MikeH. Have a look at the docs [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html#section-rest-server-authentication). You are using a Firebase Secret and this will grant the server complete read and write access to the entire Firebase. In my opinion, the firebase secret used for granting user tokens, but not use directly, which may not so safe.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should have a look at the docs [Custom Authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html)

The library you are using takes [python-firebase](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-token-generator-python) to generate tokens.
In your code,

```
auth = firebase.FirebaseAuthentication('MY_FIREBASE_SECRET','myEmail@email.com')
```

it should be:

```
auth = firebase.FirebaseAuthentication('MY_FIREBASE_SECRET','myEmail@email.com', extra={'uid': '123'})
```

The param `extra` is the payload to create token and `uid` is a must as the github page says.

Answer (score 0):

look at the file `firebase.py`, class `FirebaseApplication` function `_authenticate`: 
        replace `'auth'` by `'auth_token'` in `params.update({'auth_token': user.firebase_auth_token})`

fixes this `HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request` error but don't fix all auth problems...

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this, Go to Rules tab and set true

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
}
```

Code
from firebase import firebase

```
myFirebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://MYFIREBASE.firebaseio.com', None)

result = myFirebase.get('/users', None) 
print result
```